# LAG rows until criteria is met from helper column

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag

SQL Server 2012 database - I need to pull absence data from our timesheet system. There needs to be 1 row per absence type per employee per date, however 1 column in the result set - the "Event ID" needs to lag back to the first date value of the "absence event", based on if the days absence havs been continous working days.

I've managed to create a "helper column" which (I think) succesfully shows "Relevant" if it is the first "Event ID" of a working day chain based on the criteria above.

I need any row which does NOT have "Relevant" listed in the "Relevant" column to have the "Event ID" column lag back to the most recent row which does, as long as that row also has the same employee number/type of absence.
Any row which DOES have "Relevant" listed needs to just display the "Event ID" I've already created for that row.

I've tried a standard lag, but obviously it only moves 1 row up which isn't always to the "Relevant" event ID. Can you suggest an alternative?

Existing resultset below:

```
+---------------------------+----------+------------+-----------+----------------+------------------------+
| Employee Reference Number | Timecode | Punch Date | Relevant? | Hours or Units |    Unique Event ID     |
+---------------------------+----------+------------+-----------+----------------+------------------------+
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 01/08/2019 | Relevant  | 8.25           | 1117190107198101082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 05/08/2019 | Relevant  | 8.5            | 1117190107198105082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 06/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | 1117190107198106082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 07/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | 1117190107198107082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 08/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | 1117190107198108082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 12/08/2019 | Relevant  | 8.5            | 1117190107198112082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 13/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | 1117190107198113082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 14/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | 1117190107198114082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 15/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | 1117190107198115082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 19/08/2019 | Relevant  | 8.5            | 1117190107198119082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 20/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | 1117190107198120082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 21/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | 1117190107198121082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 22/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | 1117190107198122082019 |
|            11250305092011 | SICK     | 16/08/2019 | Relevant  | 4              | 1125030509201116082019 |
|            13255123072018 | SICK     | 09/08/2019 | Relevant  | 7.5            | 1325512307201809082019 |
|            13392717062019 | SICK     | 07/08/2019 | Relevant  | 7.5            | 1339271706201907082019 |
+---------------------------+----------+------------+-----------+----------------+------------------------+
```

Required resultset:

```
+---------------------------+----------+------------+-----------+----------------+------------------------+
| Employee Reference Number | Timecode | Punch Date | Relevant? | Hours or Units |    Unique Event ID     |
+---------------------------+----------+------------+-----------+----------------+------------------------+
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 01/08/2019 | Relevant  | 8.25           | 1117190107198101082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 05/08/2019 | Relevant  | 8.5            | 1117190107198105082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 06/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | **1117190107198105082019** |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 07/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | **1117190107198105082019 |**
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 08/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | **1117190107198105082019 |**
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 12/08/2019 | Relevant  | 8.5            | 1117190107198112082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 13/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | **1117190107198112082019 |**
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 14/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | **1117190107198112082019 |**
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 15/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | **1117190107198112082019 |**
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 19/08/2019 | Relevant  | 8.5            | 1117190107198119082019 |
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 20/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | **1117190107198119082019 |**
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 21/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | **1117190107198119082019 |**
|            11171901071981 | SICK     | 22/08/2019 |           | 8.5            | **1117190107198119082019 |**
|            11250305092011 | SICK     | 16/08/2019 | Relevant  | 4              | 1125030509201116082019 |
|            13255123072018 | SICK     | 09/08/2019 | Relevant  | 7.5            | 1325512307201809082019 |
|            13392717062019 | SICK     | 07/08/2019 | Relevant  | 7.5            | 1339271706201907082019 |
+---------------------------+----------+------------+-----------+----------------+------------------------+
```

```
SELECT 
  E.[REMARK3]+REPLACE(convert(varchar,E.[DATEEMPLOYED],103),'/','') as 'Employee Reference Number' 
  , CASE WHEN JE.[ACTIVITYNUMBER] = '810' THEN 'SICK' ELSE 'UNPLVE' END AS 'Timecode' 
  , Convert(varchar,[ENTRYDATE],103) AS 'Punch Date' 
  , case when 
    (DATEDIFF(dd, [ENTRYDATE],isnull(lag ([ENTRYDATE]) over (PARTITION BY convert(nvarchar,E.[REMARK3]+REPLACE(convert(varchar,E.[DATEEMPLOYED],103),'/','')),CASE WHEN JE.[ACTIVITYNUMBER] = '810' THEN 'SICK' ELSE 'UNPLVE' end ORDER BY JE.[ENTRYDATE] ASC),[ENTRYDATE])) + 1)
    -(DATEDIFF(wk, [ENTRYDATE], isnull(lag ([ENTRYDATE]) over (PARTITION BY convert(nvarchar,E.[REMARK3]+REPLACE(convert(varchar,E.[DATEEMPLOYED],103),'/','')),CASE WHEN JE.[ACTIVITYNUMBER] = '810' THEN 'SICK' ELSE 'UNPLVE' end ORDER BY JE.[ENTRYDATE] ASC),[ENTRYDATE])) * 2)
    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw,[ENTRYDATE]) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, isnull(lag ([ENTRYDATE]) over (PARTITION BY convert(nvarchar,E.[REMARK3]+REPLACE(convert(varchar,E.[DATEEMPLOYED],103),'/','')),CASE WHEN JE.[ACTIVITYNUMBER] = '810' THEN 'SICK' ELSE 'UNPLVE' end ORDER BY JE.[ENTRYDATE] ASC),[ENTRYDATE])) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) in ( '-1','1','2') then 'First' else '' end as 'First?' 
  , round([NUMBERREGISTERED],4,1) as 'Hours or Units' 
  , convert(nvarchar,E.[REMARK3]+REPLACE(convert(varchar,E.[DATEEMPLOYED],103),'/','')+REPLACE(convert(varchar,JE.[ENTRYDATE],103),'/','')) AS 'Unique Event ID' 
FROM [RambollDW].[Maconomy].[vw_JOBENTRY] AS JE 
left join [RambollDW].[Maconomy].[vw_EMPLOYEE] AS E ON JE.[EMPLOYEENUMBER] = E.[EMPLOYEENUMBER] 
WHERE E.[COMPANYNUMBER] in ( '162' , '310')
  AND JE.[ENTRYDATE] BETWEEN DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)) 
  AND DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)))
  AND JE.[JOBNUMBER] in ( 'ABSENCE162' , 'ABSENCE310')
  AND JE.[TASKNAME] IN ('810','821')
```

Comment: You would probably need to share a (small) subset of your original data as well.

Comment: Side note: [_please_ don't use `BETWEEN` on date/time/timestamp types, especially in SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Some spacing and other formatting also wouldn't go amiss.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a cumulative sum of what you are calling "relevant".  I would phrase this as:

```
select . . .,
       sum(case when prev_punchdate = dateadd(day, -1, punchdate)
                then 0 else 1
           end) over (partition by employee_reference order by punchdate) as episode_number
from (select . . .,
             lag(punchdate) over (partition by employee_reference order by punchdate) as prev_punchdate
      from . . .
     ) t
```

Comment: I know I probably over complicated the working day bit of my query, but would your answer above work in the scenario where the entry itself is on a Monday, but because there was also an entry on the Friday before - this should be seen as the same "Event ID" as the working days of Friday/Monday are continous..?

Comment: @SophieHarper . . . I see nothing in your question about weekends versus weekdays.

Comment: To account for Friday/Monday just add an OR in the SUM clause: sum(case when (prev_punchdate = dateadd(dd, -1, punchdate)) or (datename(dw, prev_punchdate) = 'Friday' and datename(dw, punchdate) = 'Monday') then 0 else 1 end)

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want. The trick is to create a row_number that contains the working day number across your data set. I've done that with a couple of CTE expressions, then it becomes a simple job check each row and see if there is also a row for the previous day.

First set up the date:

```
set dateformat dmy
create table punch(EmployeeID varchar(20), timecode varchar(10), Punchdate date, rel varchar(10), Hours decimal(4,2),EventID varchar(30))
insert punch values ('11171901071981','SICK','01/08/2019','Relevant','8.25','1117190107198101082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','05/08/2019','Relevant','8.5','1117190107198105082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','06/08/2019','','8.5','1117190107198106082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','07/08/2019','','8.5','1117190107198107082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','08/08/2019','','8.5','1117190107198108082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','12/08/2019','Relevant','8.5','1117190107198112082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','13/08/2019','','8.5','1117190107198113082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','14/08/2019','','8.5','1117190107198114082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','15/08/2019','','8.5','1117190107198115082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','19/08/2019','Relevant','8.5','1117190107198119082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','20/08/2019','','8.5','1117190107198120082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','21/08/2019','','8.5','1117190107198121082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','22/08/2019','','8.5','1117190107198122082019')
,('11250305092011','SICK','16/08/2019','Relevant','4','1125030509201116082019')
,('13255123072018','SICK','09/08/2019','Relevant','7.5','1325512307201809082019')
,('13392717062019','SICK','07/08/2019','Relevant','7.5','1339271706201907082019')
```

Then the query:

```
;with daterange as(
  select min(punchdate) as MinDt, max(punchdate) as MaxDt from punch
  )
, alldates as (
  select MinDt d from daterange
  union all
  select dateadd(d,1,alldates.d) from alldates 
  cross join daterange
  where d<maxDt
)
, wd as (
  select d,row_number() over(order by d) as wdnum 
  from alldates 
  where datepart(dw,d) not in (1,7)
 )
 select punch.*, wdnum
 from punch
 join wd on wd.d=punchdate
 where not exists(
   select * from punch p2
   join wd wd2 on wd2.d=p2.punchdate
   where p2.employeeid=punch.employeeid
   and wd2.wdnum=wd.wdnum-1
   )
```

Result is:

```
EmployeeID     timecode Punchdate   rel        Hours    EventID                wdnum
11171901071981 SICK 2019-08-01  Relevant    8.25 1117190107198101082019 1
11171901071981 SICK 2019-08-05  Relevant    8.5 1117190107198105082019  3
13392717062019 SICK 2019-08-07  Relevant    7.5 1339271706201907082019  5
13255123072018 SICK 2019-08-09  Relevant    7.5 1325512307201809082019  7
11171901071981 SICK 2019-08-12  Relevant    8.5 1117190107198112082019  8
11250305092011 SICK 2019-08-16  Relevant    4   1125030509201116082019  12
11171901071981 SICK 2019-08-19  Relevant    8.5 1117190107198119082019  13
```

Here is the sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8c8f7/6

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS,

```
create table #temp11(EmployeeReferenceNumber varchar(20), Timecode varchar(10), PunchDate datetime
, Relevant varchar(10) , HoursorUnits decimal(5,2) ,UniqueEventID varchar(30))
insert into #temp11 values
('11171901071981','SICK', '2019/08/01','Relevant',  8.25,'1117190107198101082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','2019/08/05','Relevant',  8.5 ,'1117190107198105082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','2019/08/06',  null,      8.5 ,'1117190107198106082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','2019/08/07',    null,    8.5 ,'1117190107198107082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','2019/08/08',   null ,    8.5 ,'1117190107198108082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','2019/08/12','Relevant',  8.5 ,'1117190107198112082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','2019/08/13',null,        8.5 ,'1117190107198113082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','2019/08/14',null,        8.5 ,'1117190107198114082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','2019/08/15',null,        8.5 ,'1117190107198115082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','2019/08/19','Relevant',  8.5 ,'1117190107198119082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','2019/08/20',null,        8.5 ,'1117190107198120082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','2019/08/21',null,        8.5 ,'1117190107198121082019')
,('11171901071981','SICK','2019/08/22',null,        8.5 ,'1117190107198122082019')
,('11250305092011','SICK','2019/08/16','Relevant',  4   ,'1125030509201116082019')
,('13255123072018','SICK','2019/08/09','Relevant',  7.5 ,'1325512307201809082019')
,('13392717062019','SICK','2019/08/07','Relevant',  7.5 ,'1339271706201907082019')

select EmployeeReferenceNumber , Timecode , PunchDate , Relevant  , HoursorUnits  
,IIF(Relevant IS NOT NULL ,T.UniqueEventID,T1.UniqueEventID )UniqueEventID
from #temp11 T
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 UniqueEventID FROM  #temp11 T1
WHERE T.EmployeeReferenceNumber=T1.EmployeeReferenceNumber AND T1.PunchDate<T.PunchDate
AND T1.Relevant IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY PunchDate DESC) T1

drop table #temp11
```